# Is it possible to avoid automatic line return in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA performs an automatic line return when the code is too long, making it difficult to read the code. **Is it possible to avoid this behavior?**

[image: auto return the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code to be in one line rather then wrapping itself

1. Go to `View` -> `Active Editor`
2. Unmark `Use Soft Wraps`

**Remember to click anywhere on the code before clicking `View` on the toolbar.**